# Maintenance on a 2013 Ford Escape 2.0L Turbo 4wd 105K miles

Tags: scheduled-maintenance

We have a 2013 Ford Escape 2.0L turbo 4wd with 105K miles. No towing, a lot of highway miles.  1.  I can't find when should we be changing the differential fluid in both units and the transfer case. At how many miles?
2. Does this vehicle really have a timing belt that needs changing at 150K miles. I thought for sure this car had a chain and I saw online the maintenance said change the belt at 150K. 
It's running fine right now. We are planning on taking it to our local Firestone shop for maintenance, needs spark plugs at 100K  (it's not missing) 
3.  We are getting the coolant changed too.  Is this a 50K service (oops) or a 100K mile service?
4.  Anything else we need to change while at this service.  The filters and oil get changed regularly so I'm only worried about the big stuff.
5.  We had the tranny fluid changed at a quick lube at 100K.  They didn't drop the pan and change the filter.  Just hooked up their pump in force out fluid machine.

Comment: Update.  I scheduled with Firestone this morning for service.  Adviser told me there isn't a scheduled service for changing differential fluid because it's not serviceable!!  Ford expects the fluid to last the life of the vehicle.  (Ford wants you to buy another one every 150K miles, in my opinion)   Explains the Youtube video I saw where the guy changing the rear diff fluid had to cut off the rear exhaust for access and there was no side case bolt access either. It was on top with no room for your hands to get in there.   Note to self,  do not cross creeks in this car!

Answer (score 1):

1) The transmission fluid should be changed at 150,000 miles, but the transfer case is a sealed unit with lifetime fluid.

2) No, only the 1.6L engine has a timing belt. The serpentine belt should be replaced at 150k along with the trans fluid.

3) Coolant is 100k miles

4) Check out your [owners manual](http://www.fordservicecontent.com/Ford_Content/catalog/owner_guides/13204om2e.pdf) on page 405. It doesn't look like there's any other maintenance aside from air filters as you mention.

5) Avoid anything that "forces" fluids through for a flush and make 100% sure you use proper fluid for the transmission - just drain/ fill as Ford dictates.